# How to support a window AC unit for a dormer window?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning, support, brackets, dormer

Does anyone have a solution for installing a window AC unit they've successfully used for a dormer window (meaning one which has part of the roof sloping down below the outside bottom edge of the window sill)? Most window AC support brackets assume that the exterior wall drops straight down from the outside edge of the sill, which isn't the case for a dormer. And unfortunately most or many of these same AC unit support brackets don't seem to allow the support arm to adjust to fit a sloping roof to press against outside the outer window sill. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, go get 2 gate sagging kits it has wire rope a turnbuckle and mount hardware then mount one to the bottom outer corner on each side "furthest from window" mount hardware to windows corners using screws long enough to get to the windows framing structure at top corners. Wire up and use turnbuckle to adjust height.  Or you could add a bracket at back mounted underneath ac and mount wires  to it

Answer (score 1):

Add legs to the AC housing that are perpendicular to the roof

Answer (score 0):

Best option I've heard, aside from building something myself (which doesn't seem practical, reliable, or safe given my limited skills) is to use a portable, floor standing AC unit on the top floor with the dormers rather than window units.